# How do you get input from a USB microphone in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, input, microphone

How do you get input from a USB microphone in Python 3?  I want to use a raspberry pi 3 model b and a USB microphone.  The USB microphone has the automatic gain off.  I want to get the decibel level of the sound the USB microphone is picking up, and I want to use that information as a variable to be used in the Python 3 program.  I **DO NOT WANT** to record sound from the USB microphone, save it as a wave file, and use the wave file in the program.  I want the program to be working with real time sound.